# MVVM - Where to load data from internet

Tags: android, mvvm

I'm trying to use this MVVM for my android app. I've done many apps, but I'm trying to step up on another level and trying to use the MVVM. But I need to understand where I should load the data from internet. I'm using RxJava, but I'm not sure if I should load data only in ViewModel. If so then where do I set the data. I'm using Databinding from google, but I don't wanna set data in xml through viewModel. I want to set it from the java file.

I'm sorry if I miswrote something, post an answer and I will try to fill out any required informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Triggering a DataLoad" is part of presentation logic. Hence, this should belong in ViewModel.

Details about "How data is loaded" for example, networking logic, does not belong to the ViewModel layer. I highly recommend using [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) as you are already using RxJava.

As `rx.Observable`and `databinding.ObservableField` are very similar, you can convert them from one form to another. I have written a [library](http://github.com/manas-chaudhari/android-mvvm) that allows you to do this. See [FieldUtils.java](https://github.com/manas-chaudhari/android-mvvm/blob/master/android-mvvm/src/main/java/com/manaschaudhari/android_mvvm/FieldUtils.java) for an implementation.

Either ways, assuming you have a `DataService` interface/class:

```
public interface DataService {
   Observable<String> loadSomeData();
}
```

you can build your ViewModel as follows:

```
public class ExampleViewModel {
    ObservableField<String> title;

    public ExampleViewModel(DataService dataService) {
        this.title = FieldUtils.toField(dataService.loadSomeData());
    }
}
```

Then, you can display this in your View using Data Binding syntax

```
<TextView
    android:text="@{viewModel.title}" />
```

I recently blogged about using RxJava with MVVM. I showed an app which loads a list of events from Github using Retrofit and displays them in a RecyclerView. This has been implemented in MVVM.

Article link:
[MVVM using RxJava + Data Binding example: Loading data using Retrofit](http://manaschaudhari.com/blog/2016/09/05/rxjava-meets-data-binding-part-4/)

A more complicated example which also shows a loading indicator and error: [DataLoadingViewModel.java](https://github.com/manas-chaudhari/android-mvvm/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/manaschaudhari/android_mvvm/sample/functional/DataLoadingViewModel.java).

Comment: Thank you for your answer I appreciate it. Sadly I had to learn it the hard way on my own (it took me only few days of studying other projects). Back to the answer, I am actually using the Retrofit in my project with RxJava. I now understand that I need to load data in the ViewModel and the binding is set trough it. But for example I'm not sure if its alright to setup RecyclerView in the view (activity). Also I would like to know, why not use @Bindable instead of ObservableField (even though it seems same, at least to me), if there is some difference let me know too. Thank you once again :)

Answer (score 0):

There is two similar architectural patterns - MVP and MVVM. The main difference is that in MVP parttern Presenter desides how to display data, but in MVVM pattern View receives Model and renders itself (takes data from model). Classical MVVM example is view bindig. But the point is - nomatter what pattern you use, you should obtain all data in Model - and place all your business logic in Model too.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, I should load, work and save data in the ViewModel and then set it to View via the ViewModel. So the View itself has almost zero operations with data? I'm sorry, I'm just trying to understand the pattern correctly.